Why won't Bixby or Google Assistant work while I record?
I'm on Samsung Galaxy S24 Ultra. If I have a recording active, then I find that Bixby and Google Assistant refuse to enable listening in the background to wake up, by calling them up using voice.
Google Assistant can't start when another app is using the microphone

I can start them manually, so the problem is not exclusive access to the microphone.
I've tried like five different recording apps and I just get the same message, when I try to activate it in settings.
I'm not really sure what the problem is here.

Please confirm that you don't have a mobile device management (MDM) or enterprise mobility management (EMM) installed on the device and which version of Android / Samsung One UI are you running.

At the very least, when I tried on Pixel 3a, a toast message "Google Assistant can't start when another app is using the microphone" appeared.

Yes, Andrew. That is the exact message I get. It's weird, cause it can't be an exclusive access thing, cause I can start the app manually, while recording.

Odd, on a Pixel 6a Android 13 (stock with no EMM/MDM) using Audio Recorder the Google Assistant was able to pickup a basic command (light on/off), and Audio Recorder captured the audio as well while in foreground the entire time.

Related: https://developer.android.com/media/platform/sharing-audio-input
